# How to calculate the force required to tip a floating dock

Tags: marine-engineering, centre-of-gravity

If I have the following I'd like to determine how wide the base of a floating dock would need to be to prevent tipping under certain weather conditions (wind & waves)

I'd like to build a modular dock floating dock on a mooring (floating, not on pilings or attached to a fixed dock). The boat is 24' in length and the beam (width) is 8'. The boat weighs 2,000lb. All of the weight of the boat will be on top of the dock in a cradle so its center of gravity could be 3' off the top of the dock. The boat would be secured to the dock when not in use so I guess you could consider this a single system.

Given potential winds of 100mph in rare cases and waves that could reach 2' - 3' in height is there a way to calculate the dimension of the floating dock so the base itself would prevent tipping?

The alternative I've considered is a ballast attached to the underside of the dock. If the size of the floating dock itself would need to be too large what is the calculation I should use to determine the necessary ballast weight and depth trade off?

Comment: The wind is not a big deal on the dock due to the limited exposure, however, the wave caused by the wind can be the troublemaker. You need to figure out how to calculate the maximum height of the wave and associated hydrodynamic force.

Comment: For a given design under worst case conditions (cargo placed in weird places, max wind, waves, etc), calculate minimum torque as a function of tilt angle required to further tilt the dock.  You can then convert to more useful numbers such as force at the extremities or pressure distributions.  You should also consider structural effects of waves- there are some good reasons not opt for a single rigid structure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just trying to try a conceptual way to set the path for further study of your floating dock.

Let's cut a 1ft section by 8 ft wide and assume it has 3ft walls and a draft of 1 ft.

Then as per your specs, it has a mass of 80lbs at 3 ft high.

Let's assume a 3ft wave crashing into it will cause it to lean into the water at one side by 2ft.

So you have an overturning moment of $80lbs *3*2/8=80*3/4= 60 \ lbs/ft$

Your restoring moment is the moment of buoyancy of the 0 by 7 by 3ft triangle of water displacement about the CG of the float which is at$ \ 3/4 ft$ of the center of the dock. The CG of buoyancy is at

$1+7*2/3=1+4.66=5.66ft \ 5.66 - 4.75=0.91ft arm$

Buoyancy is $7*3/2=10.5* 62.5=656.25lbs$

$656.25*0.91=597.1lbs ft>60 lbs ft \ OK.$

So with the above assumptions, your float will not capsize. All assumptions.

I will get back to this with a figure and more detail. The big question is the impact of the wave.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but to show the complicated nature of current, and what might occur. After all, the current that creates a wave is non-static, which might cause a random pressure diagram against the boat. The sketch below demonstrates a most unfavorable condition - positive pressure at one end and negative on the other.

If you are truly interested in this matter, I think you shall visit websites that cover the topics such as deepwater/ocean engineering, or ship-building.

[image]